# Since when am I a robot?

Tags: support

Every time I try to post an answer to a challenge here, I get this annoying "Are you a robot?" prompt. I've solved it countless times but it still stops me every time I try to post an answer.

How do I make it stop?

Comment: @a'_' Since maybe two days ago. Never had an issue before that.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Interestingly, I get the prompt consistently for months by now ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### "Explain" your program

That's usually the workaround I do to avoid the CAPTCHA. Because if you explain your program, the spam checker will think that you're a human being and therefore stop the CAPTCHA.

Do you think that typing all that explanation is a nuisance? Hint: Adding just another "Explanation" section without containing an explanation of your program also helps! (Note that you should be editing in the section after you pasted your submission, otherwise it won't work.)

Answer (score 3):

One possible explanation is the speed at which you post. I usually get this prompt if I code out my answer on TIO (which is pretty typical), and then copy the SE-formatted text into the answer box and immediately hit submit. Since your answers are conventionally TIO-formatted, I assume you do the same.

What I typically do is just add a bit -- just a line or two is usually enough -- to explain approximately my approach. I think the prompt appears just because it assumes you're a robot if you open the answer box and then submit a full-length answer within like 1 second.

I haven't tested this, but you might be able to click on the answer box to open it, and then go code in TIO, and then when you finish, come back and paste your solution and submit it. This might get the prompt to not appear because you'll be spending more than half a second between opening the answer field and submitting.

**Edit** I discarded my draft and then opened the answer box and pasted this answer in and immediately submitted. It gave me the prompt. I discarded the draft and then opened the answer box and watched a YouTube video before pasting this answer in and immediately submitting, and it didn't give me the prompt, so the method in my third paragraph *should* work.

Comment: For paragraph #3, I just tested it and it didn't work. (I tried clicking as slowly as possible and it still gave me the spam filter...) I guess on Meta the system works differently.

Comment: @a'_' that's weird. the way i did it is i just clicked on the answer input field, waited like 5 minutes, and then copy-pasted something in and immediately submitted it, and it worked for me. if not, probably just stick to paragraph 2 (or the other suggestions)